# IISExpress not running all projects in solution Visual Studio 2022

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2022

I have a solution with several ASP.NET web applications.  In previous versions of VS, debugging any one of those apps would also start the others in IIS Express as shown under Sites.

VS 2022 was working fine until the last update.  Now it's a mixed bag on what runs when you starting an application.   In one case only the application that was started appears in IIS Express->Sites.  In another, the target app plus another appears.

I've double-checked my project settings and each is set to run in IIS Express.

[image]

The only setting I started to use is the Enable Edit and Continue for the new Hot Reload.  It seems like the trouble started after that feature came out.

Anybody else have the same problem and hopefully found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.

Under the Solution itself, is a section for Startup Project.   In here you can change it to run the currently selected project, a Single Project, or Multiple projects.

1. Right-click on the Solution and choose Properties.
2. In the left pane, choose Startup Project
3. Choose Multiple startup-projects
4. For each project you want to run at the same time, change its Action to Start.

Comment: The actual cause was that since VS2019, separate web projects use separate IIS Express configuration files, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file So, you cannot expect launch a single project on IIS Express will also launch others (since they are not in the same config file now).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put **bitness**, in debug option, to **x86** and it worked fine for me.

I have a windows version with x64, but for some reason in vs2022 IIS express doesn't work with x64.

Pay attention that the configuration is written also in your *.csproj* file of your

application, so if you use TFS or similar and check-in, it will be default option for who will use the application later.